# python - print datetime directives to console?

Tags: python, datetime, strftime, strptime

I can't remember all the directives for datetime, any handy way to print the list with explanation to the console inside python code or python prompt?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

```
 Directive |    Meaning |   Example | Notes  
  %a |  Weekday as locale’s abbreviated name.    |Sun, Mon, ..., Sat  (en_US); So, Mo, ..., Sa (de_DE) |(1)  
  %A |  Weekday as locale’s full name. | ....
  ....
```

why?
in a restricted environment like some contest where internet is not available,   browser access is not available not any saved material is allowed.

Anyway possible?

Comment: You could always save it as a string and then print it whenever you want. Or you could keep a browser window handy for looking things up (probably more convenient).

Comment: what if internet access is denied?

Comment: Store the string list statically in your python source code as a variable, function, class, etc.

Comment: The Windows Python installation has a Doc directory containing a Windows help file of Python documentation.  I don't know about the Linux install.

Comment: @Mark ok, can you please tell me the name and path of the file in windows? i'll try to find at relative similar paths in linux

Comment: <Where_ever_you_installed_Python>\Doc.  There's only one file in it.  It has a reference on the Start menu as well.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is python uses the underlying OS for `strftime` and `strptime`. That means "python" doesn't know. You can query the underlying OS man page.

Not sure this qualifies as "handy", but works without internet access:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> print subprocess.check_output(['man', 'strftime'])

STRFTIME(3)                                         Linux Programmer's Manual                                        STRFTIME(3)
NAME
   strftime - format date and time
SYNOPSIS
   #include <time.h>

   size_t strftime(char *s, size_t max, const char *format,
           const struct tm *tm);
...
```

Comment: Good tip on the fact tnat the help is in the system's manual pages.